# How do I deploy Apollo client and Node Express/Sequelize API?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, graphql, apollo-client

I have an Apollo app with an express/sequelize API. It runs fine in dev. Can anyone tell me what it should look like in prod? Ive added .env environment variables. Where do those get set on the web server? Do I change the url in Apollo client? How do I build/prepare the API for deployment to web server through FTP? I use bitbucket for CI/CD. I really don't what I'm supposed to do.

Comment: The easiest way to host a Node.js application is using a cloud provider dedicated to run JavaScript like [AWS lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/), [Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/), [Zeit's Now](https://zeit.co/). Especially the latter ones should have extensive documentation. How to operate web applications is unfortunately not a Stack Overflow answer but a whole professional field.

Comment: This inadvertently answers my question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So basically the answer is, with Node, you can't just deploy to a static server and expect it to work. The app created is already it's own server. Therefore, you have to host on in a service like AWS, Heroku or Now to get it to work. This may seem obvious to some but at first this wasn't clear to me.